# How can I encrypt a password with Blowfish in Perl?

Tags: perl, encryption

Can anyone tell me where can I find a Perl program which decrypts a password
and then encrypts it using the blowfish algorithm? I found one but it is in Java, but I don't know much about that language. =(

anyway.. thanks for those who answered, esp to Konstantinos? hmm.

Answer (score 5):

The language is called Perl, not PERL, and the first port of call for looking to do almost anything with it is the CPAN, which has lots of modules for dealing with [Blowfish](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=blowfish&mode=all).

Answer (score 4):

http://www.koders.com/default.aspx?s=blowfish+encrypt+decrypt+&btn=&la=Perl&li=*

[Crypt::Blowfish](http://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::Blowfish)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Password "encryption" is typically implemented via hashing, which means that it's not reversible.

For the second part of your question, you can [search CPAN for Blowfish modules](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=blowfish&mode=module).